# Dlookup not evaluating double criteria properly

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using this code to do a Dlookup with two criteria. But it returns values even if both criteria are not matched in the same record.  Note that if I put a value instead of 'heat' that does not exist at all in the table then Dlookup does not return a value. I seams it's looking for the criteria separately and not combined in the same record.

I tried this

```
 DLookup("[Risk ID]", "RA", "[Hazard Category] ='Heat' And [Safety Tag number] = " & SafetyTagNbr)
```

and This

```
DLookup("[Risk ID]", "RA", "[Safety tag number] = " & SafetyTagNbr & " AND [Hazard Category] ='Heat'")
```

Answer (score 2):

For `DLookup()` you need to insert:

```
DLookup( "ColumnName", "TableName", "Criteria")
```

Your syntax is correct, but only if `[Safety Tag number]` is a `Number`. If not, then you have to use for your second criteria a `String`:

```
DLookup("[Risk ID]", "RA", "[Hazard Category] ='Heat' And [Safety Tag number] = '" & SafetyTagNbr & "'")
```

If you have more records in your table which statisfie your criteria, then `DLookup()` returns the first record he finds in the table.

Comment: Figured it out. There was actually a typo in the [Safety Tag number] field name. So It would ignore that criteria.